# Get total number of tables in database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

How do I get total number of tables in c#. This is what i tried. it returns true.

```
conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connString;
conn.Open();
string queryss = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'bluevels_local_sis'";
MySqlCommand cmdaa = new MySqlCommand(queryss, conn);
MySqlDataReader dataReaderxx = cmdaa.ExecuteReader();
dataReaderxx.Read();
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dataReaderxx.HasRows));
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the column value from the returned result set.

```cs
dataReaderxx.Read();
dataReaderxx.GetInt32(0)
```

Comment: You can simplify the code a lot by using `ExecuteScalar` instead of doing a `ExecuteReader` when your result has only one row and one column (like a count) ExecuteScalar will return that value.

Answer (score 1):

Close, just use `ExecuteScalar()` to get a single value. No Data reader necessary

```
    string queryss = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'bluevels_local_sis'";
    using(conn = new MySqlConnection(connString)){
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmdaa = new MySqlCommand(queryss, conn);
        MessageBox.Show(cmdaa.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }
```